# magento upsell missing first item everytime

Tags: magento

Magento ver. 1.7.0.2, Up Sells show on the product page but never the first product I add as an up sell. For example if I ad a,b,c,d as up sell products, and yes I am reindexing, I go check the product page and only b,c,d are displaying. It's not a specific product issue as it happens the exact same when mixing and matching simple & configurable products and testing with different items.

It seems to be like somewhere an array is starting at one instead of zero, any ideas?

Comment: have you the limit for up-sell product to display. try to add only 2 product under up-sell and check for same issue.

Comment: Yes same issue, when I have two set it only shows 1. I also tried changing the position but that had no effect at all.